# Getting a PathError in AWS Lambda when calling Gateway API Go function

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm setting up a AWS Lambda function that runs Go 1.x that I call with a web hook on a form submit on my website. 
This is the [AWS Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOh7Z.png) and [Gateway POST request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9u8Jp.png)

When I call the Gateway API
[Gateway API Endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iV6pO.png) I get a return of `errorMessage":"fork/exec /var/task/WebhookForm: no such file or directory","errorType":"PathError` the `WebhookForm` is the function that I should be invoking but I can't seem to figure this problem out.

```
//WebhooksForm/main.go
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/smtp"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

func HandleRequest(ctx context.Context, name MyEvent) (string, error) {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Hello!"), nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(HandleRequest)
}
```